# Unity AudioMixer sets AudioSources to 0 regardless of decibel value

Tags: unity, audio

My code for the decibel and volume/linear conversion is good already. I just can't figure out why my AudioMixer keeps on setting my AudioSources to 0. I've double checked to see if my decibel value on my AudioMixer is updating. It updates accordingly. But, my AudioSources remain to have a volume of 0 regardless of any update or not.

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: Please walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of this issue, starting from a new empty project. Once we can reproduce the problem you're experiencing, we can test solutions to be sure they solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update. when I tried reproducing the problem on a fresh project, it works. Just then, I realized that one of my old scripts updates the volume of the `AudioSource` before the other script can validly update the volume.

Comment: This is one reason we recommend creating a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example to include when initially posting a question - the process often helps isolate relevant bits of your project where the problem's root cause might be lurking.